# Back Button image not showing up after showing/hiding SearchBar

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, searchbar

I have a SearchBar in my NavigationBar. When the SearchBar is clicked, I am having it show over the "Back" button on the Navigation bar. However, when I re-show the "Back" button, the arrow next to it is no longer visible. Here is what I mean:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@interface SearchViewController ()

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    [searchBar sizeToFit];
    searchBar.delegate = self;

    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
[searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
}

@end
```

Any ideas on why this might be happening? Thanks!

Comment: I wonder, does taking out the two lines: `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO / YES;` still move/hide the arrow?

Comment: @theMonster nope the arrow stays. However, the SearchBar doesn't extend to the full length of the nav bar (which is what I need)

Comment: have you tried using `[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES / NO animated:YES];` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add this line to method `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:searchBar:`

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much! I've tried so many different variations, not sure how I missed this. Thanks for the quick help. Will accept in 2 min

Comment: @user1282637 Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
*- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
    [searchBar sizeToFit];
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
[searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
}
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
}
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
}*
```